# How to remove anaconda from path in mac in order to pip install?

Tags: pip, anaconda, python-idle, macos-big-sur, python-install

MacBook Pro already had one python 3.8.2 installation. Then I installed anaconda which has python 3.8.5 and installed python 3.9.4 from python.org.

Pip3 is installing packages to anaconda, not for 3.9.4. How to install packages for python 3.9.4 using pip3 from the terminal? Also, how to run python 3.8.2, 3.8.5, 3.9.4 separately from the terminal (along with their respective idle)?

I am not familiar with changing paths, so detailed commands will be very helpful.

```
(base) ~ % where python3
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
(base) ~ % where pip3
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
(base) ~ % where python
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
(base) ~ % where pip
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `pip3`. Use `pip3.8` or `pip3.9` or start pip with an explicit python.

```
pythonx-m pip install package
```

where `pythonx` is `python3.9` or `python3.8`.  I suspect that `python3.8` still starts 3.8.2, but to be sure, just enter `python3.8` on the command line and look at startup line.  I don't know anything about starting Anaconda python.

Similarly, `python3.x` -m idlelib` will start IDLE with whatever python3.x starts.

Comment: Any way to use the native Python 3.8.2? `Python3.8` opens the Python3.8.5 installed using anaconda.

Comment: On Windows, `py -3.8` should open only python.org installs, but I cannot answer for using Terminal on Mac.  If you can find the 3.8.2 folder in Finder, it should contain the 3.8.2 binary, but that does not get you pip, etc.